# Docker not recognising Dockerfile

Tags: django, docker, heroku, dockerfile

I am running into a problem where docker isn't recognising my Dockerfile.

***-What I am trying to do:***

Make a docker upload of an existing heroku app.

***-**The error that occurs:*****

`failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount649479195/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

***-What I have tried:***

Ensuring docker file is where my `manage.py` file is and ensuring it has the title `Dockerfile`.

***-My set up:***

I have a django project in a folder on on my desktop. The folder is called `site1`.
In the folder is all the django files. Including my `manage.py` and `Dockerfile` I have created.
My heroku app is called: `tactilefire`. My django app is called `site1app`. My docker file consists of:

```
FROM python:3.8
ADD . /site1/
WORKDIR /site1
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y pandoc
RUN apt-get install -y texlive-fonts-recommended
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT site1.wsgi
```

so when I try build my docker i get the error.
Any ideas? there must be something wrong with my set up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is actually called `Dockerfile.txt`. It must be named `Dockerfile`, with no file extension.

Rename it and try again.